# Creating chart out of ember-cli-blanket report in Jenkins

Tags: ember.js, jenkins, ember-addon

I have integrated `ember-cli-blanket` in my Jenkins job successfully. And the `ember test` will generate a output file in JSON format(eg: coverage-report.json).
Now for making it more user friendly or making it more understandable, I need to show a chart/graph which describes the result of test(content of coverage-report.json), after the build finishes successfully.
I have tried some Jenkins plugin like, cucumber plugin, cucumber reports plugin, cucumber JSON test reporting etc. But nothing works.

Is there any way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: jenkins supports a format called "junit" (sometimes called "xunit") out of the box. i'm currently looking for a way to get this working

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will also go through it.